# How to get row and column of a moused-over cell in WPF DataGrid cell?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am working with WPF DataGrid. I want to be able to detect which cell (row and index) my mouse is currently hovered over then set focus/highlight  that cell. I was able to find this [tutorial](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2008/12/wpf-datagrid-detecting-clicked-cell-and-row/) on how to find row and index but it seems really complicated. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score -3):

Override DataGridCell template and then redesign it. It's relatively easy, you only need to add new trigger for IsMouseOver.

Comment: can you be more specific on "redesign it"?